# How To Reconfigure Class File Paths In a FLA File?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3, flash-ide

I have a lot of library assets linked to external as3 classes. I would like to change the structure of the packages containing the linked classes, but if I do so, all links will get broken.

**Is there any way to automatically or at least easily tell the FLA file where to get the new class files from? Could a FLA file be configured to read this sort of information from a configuration file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a folder to the source paths in ActionScript Settings. So if you had linked all your classes relative to the 'myClasses' folder, and then you moved everything to a different folder, you'd just have to update that one source path and it would find all the classes again.

Also, maybe this obvious, but I didn't realize it for a long time:
You can edit the class linkage right in the Library panel (without having to open the Properties for each symbol). Just double-click the linkage path.

Comment: Would setting paths in the ActionScript Settings help me in the following scenario? :

Sprite_A linked to com.core.classes.Class1
Sprite_B linked to com.core.classes.Class2
Sprite_C linked to org.utility.ClassX
Sprite_D linked to org.utility.ClassZ

core.classes becomes thisandthat so then I get:
core.thisandthat.Class1
core.thisandthat.Class2

org.utility becomes org.utility.pack.deep so then I get:
org.utility.pack.deep.ClassX
org.utility.pack.deep.ClassZ

//

Thanks for the tip on quickly editing the links by double clicking fields under AS Linkage.

Comment: Not really. It would only help if you had initially listed `com.core.classes` and `org.utility` in the source paths. Then classes would just be linked as Class1, ClassX, etc. So by changing the paths to `core.thisandthat` you could still just have those relative linkages. I wouldn't really recommend doing it that way though as you can easily get naming conflicts. Just wasn't sure exactly what you were trying to accomplish.